# view server state permission was denied

Tags: sql-server, permissions

The strangest thing is happening on my SQL Server Management Studio.
When I right-click any table, I get a "VIEW SERVER STATE permission was denied on object 'server', database 'master'. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)" error, but if I just click OK, then the context menu appears and I keep working just the same.
Again, if I right-click in Columns, Keys, whatever, inside the table, everything works fine.
Any ideas??

Comment: Run the profiler to see what is executing to cause that error. SQL Server permissions are a bitch of note to get right.

Comment: If I remember right, you might get this error if the SSMS isn't patched to the latest service pack, but I don't recall the specific version/SP combo.

Comment: I encountered this after a database version upgrade. Solution was to install new version of SSMS to match new DB version.

Comment: Same issue with one of our users using SQL 2012 SSMS to connect to SQL 2014 DB. When right-clicking on view, he got the same error and granting db_owner to the database in question or even master didn't help. I found that by granting "processadmin" server role, the error went away. No idea why. There is probably a less privileged permission I could grant but haven't found it.